# report_text from report not working with lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops, report, t-test

I want to report a couple of t-tests using `report_text()` from `report`. My tests are stored in a list. I'm able to report the tests outside the lists, but nothing that I do seems to work to **unlist my tests and report them**

- Works just fine:

```
a <- t.test(data$ARG_L1, data$ARG_L2, data = data, paired = T)
report_text(a)

### output: 
Effect sizes were labelled following Cohen's (1988) recommendations.
The Paired t-test testing the difference between data$ARG_L1 and data$ARG_L2 (mean of the
differences = 6.35) suggests that the effect is positive, statistically significant, and large (difference = 6.35, 95% CI [4.42, 8.27], t(44) = 6.65, p < .001; Cohen's d = 0.99, 95% CI [0.63,1.35])
```

- Cannot report:

```
### set list outsite loop:

tests <- list()

### run loop:

for (zz in seq(from = 1, to = 4, by = 2)) {
  
  PairedVar1 <- data[zz+1]     #1 Variables
  PairednVar1 <- names(PairedVar1)
  data$PairedVar1Unlist <- unlist(PairedVar1)
  
  PairedVar2 <- data[zz+2]     #2 Variables
  PairednVar2 <- names(PairedVar2)
  data$PairedVar2Unlist <- unlist(PairedVar2)
  
  ### run the test:
  
  tests[[zz]] <- t.test(data$PairedVar1Unlist, data$PairedVar2Unlist,
                                         paired = T, data =  data, exact = F)
  
tests[[zz]]$data.name <- str_glue("{PairednVar1} and {PairednVar2}") ### write the names    
}

 report_text(tests)
Error: Oops, objects of class [list] are not supported (yet) by report_text() :(
Want to help? Check out https://easystats.github.io/report/articles/new_models.html
```

- Attempts (no one worked):

```
report_text(unlist(tests))
report_text(tests[[1]])
report_text(bind_rows(tests))
tests <- tests %>% discard(is.null)
report_text(tests)
```

- **Question:** : How can I unlist the tests and report them with `report` ? I'm sure there's a way. Thanks in advance.
- data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(ID = structure(c("PART_1", "PART_2", "PART_3", 
"PART_4", "PART_5", "PART_6", "PART_7", "PART_8", "PART_9", "PART_10", 
"PART_11", "PART_12", "PART_13", "PART_14", "PART_15", "PART_16", 
"PART_17", "PART_18", "PART_19", "PART_20", "PART_21", "PART_22", 
"PART_23", "PART_24", "PART_25", "PART_26", "PART_27", "PART_28", 
"PART_29", "PART_30", "PART_31", "PART_32", "PART_33", "PART_34", 
"PART_35", "PART_36", "PART_37", "PART_38", "PART_39", "PART_40", 
"PART_41", "PART_42", "PART_43", "PART_44", "PART_45", "PART_46", 
"PART_47", "PART_48", "PART_49", "PART_50", "PART_51", "PART_52", 
"PART_53", "PART_54", "PART_55", "PART_56", "PART_57", "PART_58", 
"PART_59", "PART_60", "PART_61", "PART_62", "PART_63", "PART_64", 
"PART_65", "PART_66", "PART_67", "PART_68", "PART_69", "PART_70", 
"PART_71"), class = c("glue", "character")), ARG_L1 = c(70.18, 
67.65, 71.89, 70.42, NaN, 72.38, 69.67, 75.63, 76.7, 76.21, 66.5, 
70.57, 76.72, 66.4, 74.75, 79.17, 70.84, NA, 67.82, 70, 71.88, 
74.55, 69.33, 69.5, 65.25, 75.05, 75.44, 64.56, 74.88, 74.29, 
72.4, 71.93, NA, 69.12, 71.43, 77.53, NA, 71.93, 70.4, 60.25, 
NA, NA, 64.8, 69, NA, 71.19, 71.12, 75.04, 68.89, 68.26, 75.81, 
NA, NA, NA, 75.89, 68.82, 77.35, 68.38, 76.71, 79.12, 78.89, 
73.5, NA, 69.7, 69.82, 70.91, NaN, 72, 71.17, 71.85, 69.7), ARG_L2 = c(65.7, 
65.8, 74.45, 68, NA, NA, 53.75, 73.94, 67.24, 58.22, NA, NaN, 
71.07, 68.07, NaN, 69.88, 71.32, 62.18, 58.65, 76.45, 71.13, 
67.25, NaN, 51.76, 69.33, 68.17, 58, 54.27, 68.05, NaN, NA, 61, 
61.67, NA, 67.79, 65.93, NA, NA, 59.27, 69.67, 71.38, 70, NaN, 
64.88, 68.19, 62.06, 61, 55.48, 65.67, 67.72, 68.47, 64, 65.11, 
66, 67.5, 66.33, NA, 69.61, 69.33, 75.67, 68.17, 63, NA, 58.81, 
NA, NA, NA, 66.5, 62.33, 65, NA), NARR_L1 = c(74.26, NA, NA, 
70.94, NaN, 75, 66.14, 74.48, 77.07, 73.47, 76, 60.44, 73.92, 
77.19, 71.4, 77.59, 72, NA, 70.38, 65.47, 70.54, NA, 68.09, 64.61, 
66.5, 72.52, 62.59, 69.25, 71.48, 71.88, 74.4, 70.1, NA, 70, 
69.6, 78.04, 62.3, 68.79, 73.44, 72.25, NA, NA, 67, 68.25, NA, 
NA, 65.94, 75.71, 72.43, 69.68, 76, 68.6, 65.65, NA, 70.43, 74, 
71.76, 71.17, 74.63, 74.22, NA, 69.47, NA, 68.72, 67, 62.82, 
NaN, 77.33, 69.76, 75.42, 67.62), NARR_L2 = c(65.08, 61, NA, 
71.18, 68.46, NA, 62.75, 66.32, 73.42, 59.83, NA, 51.8, 64.77, 
67.88, NaN, 72.27, 64.25, NaN, 62.6, 54.75, 64.74, NA, NaN, 51.58, 
67.05, 62.38, 64.57, NA, 65.56, NaN, NA, 70.71, NA, NA, 68.1, 
NA, 58.43, NA, 55, 65.29, NA, 58.86, NaN, 64.18, NA, 70.33, 58.5, 
64.84, 65.19, 63.14, 59.12, NaN, 62.75, NA, NaN, 68.82, 65.04, 
66.78, 64.86, 69.06, 69.94, 59.31, 65.15, 55.83, 67.71, NA, NA, 
69, 58.83, 60.65, NA), PairedVar1Unlist = c(74.26, NA, NA, 70.94, 
NaN, 75, 66.14, 74.48, 77.07, 73.47, 76, 60.44, 73.92, 77.19, 
71.4, 77.59, 72, NA, 70.38, 65.47, 70.54, NA, 68.09, 64.61, 66.5, 
72.52, 62.59, 69.25, 71.48, 71.88, 74.4, 70.1, NA, 70, 69.6, 
78.04, 62.3, 68.79, 73.44, 72.25, NA, NA, 67, 68.25, NA, NA, 
65.94, 75.71, 72.43, 69.68, 76, 68.6, 65.65, NA, 70.43, 74, 71.76, 
71.17, 74.63, 74.22, NA, 69.47, NA, 68.72, 67, 62.82, NaN, 77.33, 
69.76, 75.42, 67.62), PairedVar2Unlist = c(65.08, 61, NA, 71.18, 
68.46, NA, 62.75, 66.32, 73.42, 59.83, NA, 51.8, 64.77, 67.88, 
NaN, 72.27, 64.25, NaN, 62.6, 54.75, 64.74, NA, NaN, 51.58, 67.05, 
62.38, 64.57, NA, 65.56, NaN, NA, 70.71, NA, NA, 68.1, NA, 58.43, 
NA, 55, 65.29, NA, 58.86, NaN, 64.18, NA, 70.33, 58.5, 64.84, 
65.19, 63.14, 59.12, NaN, 62.75, NA, NaN, 68.82, 65.04, 66.78, 
64.86, 69.06, 69.94, 59.31, 65.15, 55.83, 67.71, NA, NA, 69, 
58.83, 60.65, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -71L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hello Larissa, What error gives your attemp `report_text(tests[[1]])`?

Comment: How about `lapply(tests, report_text)`?

Comment: @Ric Villalba , the error is: Warning message:
In .effectsize_t.test(model, type = type, verbose = verbose, ...) :
  Unable to retrieve data from htest object. Using t_to_d() approximation.

Comment: @Limey , now I get: lapply(tests, report_text)
Error: Oops, objects of class [NULL] are not supported (yet) by report_text() :(

Want to help? Check out https://easystats.github.io/report/articles/new_models.html
In addition: Warning message:
In .effectsize_t.test(model, type = type, verbose = verbose, ...) :
  Unable to retrieve data from htest object. Using t_to_d() approximation.

Comment: That suggests that something is going wrong with at least one of your tests in your `for` loop.  Either that our you have a lazy evaluation problem (because you're using a `for` loop...)  You can get more information on lazy evaluation [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation).

Comment: @Limey, seems the problem is that he is iterating `by = 2` steps, thus the list has empty even positions. @Larissa, i suggest use  `test <- t.test(data$PairedVar1Unlist, data$PairedVar2Unlist,  paired = T, data =  data, exact = F)` then `test$data.name <- str_glue("{PairednVar1} and {PairednVar2}")` then `tests = append(tests, test)` instead

Comment: @RicVillalba  Agreed. My answer below circumvents the issue. We posted simmultaneously.

Comment: Hi , Limey and @Ric Vilalba , thanks, but I still can't make ```report_text``` work. I was aware of the null positions, I've deleted them with ```discard(is.null)``` , but it still didn't work.  I'm guessing that the problem is because the results are in a list (it's a guess), but I can't get my head around that...

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop creates an element of `tests` which is `NULL`:

```
[[2]]
NULL
```

Converting from `for` loop to `lapply` solves the problem [I also changed the name of your data frame from `data` to `df` to avoid potential clashes with the `data()` function]:

```
tests <- lapply(
  seq(from = 1, to = 4, by = 2),
  function(zz) {
  
    PairedVar1 <- df[zz+1]     #1 Variables
    PairednVar1 <- names(PairedVar1)
    df$PairedVar1Unlist <- unlist(PairedVar1)
  
    PairedVar2 <- df[zz+2]     #2 Variables
    PairednVar2 <- names(PairedVar2)
    df$PairedVar2Unlist <- unlist(PairedVar2)
  
  ### run the test:
  
    rv <- t.test(df$PairedVar1Unlist, df$PairedVar2Unlist,
                          paired = T, data =  df, exact = F)
  
    rv$data.name <- str_glue("{PairednVar1} and {PairednVar2}") ### write the names    
    rv
  }
)
tests
[[1]]

    Paired t-test

data:  ARG_L1 and ARG_L2
t = 6.6524, df = 44, p-value = 3.703e-08
alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 4.423911 8.269422
sample estimates:
mean difference 
       6.346667 


[[2]]

    Paired t-test

data:  NARR_L1 and NARR_L2
t = 9.895, df = 41, p-value = 1.999e-12
alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 5.732389 8.672373
sample estimates:
mean difference 
       7.202381
```

Then you should be able to `lapply` as I mentioned in my comment.

```
lapply(tests, report_text)
```

I don't have the `report` package installed, so I cannot confirm.

Comment: hi , thank you, but It still doesn't work. I was aware of the empty values, that's why I've tried before  ```tests2 <- tests %>% discard(is.null)``` but It still doesn't work, any thoughts? (ps: also doesn't work: ```lapply(tests2, report_text)``` )

Comment: following your code, I still get: Warning messages:
1: In .effectsize_t.test(model, type = type, verbose = verbose, ...) :
  Unable to retrieve data from htest object. Using t_to_d() approximation.
2: In .effectsize_t.test(model, type = type, verbose = verbose, ...) :
  Unable to retrieve data from htest object. Using t_to_d() approximation.

Comment: yes, I get those warnings too.  But they are warnings, not errors.  After installing the `report` package, `lapply(tests, report_text)` gives the expected output.

Comment: why shouldn't I be concerned about them? I don't understand why I dont get them without the list (in my first example in the post)

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't be concerned about them. But they are not relevant to the question you asked, which related to preventing errors when looping.  If you now want to remove the warning messages, that's a separate question and one I cannot help you with as I am not sufficently familar with the `report` package.